# TypeScript: NgRx effect to trigger an action

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ngrx

Am new to NgRx most of my code is working fine but am stuck at this particular one and I will be need your help .

When Login Effect as been triggered and its successfully sent to LoginSuccess am trying to save to localstorage and trigger another action.

Below is my sample code

**Effect**

```
    @Effect({ dispatch: false })
    LogInSuccess$: Observable<any> = this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType<businessActions.LogInSuccess>(
            businessActions.AuthActionTypes.LOGIN_SUCCESS
        ),
        map((action: businessActions.LogInSuccess) => {
            localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(action.payload));
            this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('/home');
        }), map(
            () => new businessActions.LoadBiz()
        )
    );
```

Comment: It's unclear what your problem is

Comment: When the addServiceSuccess is dispacthed, it will show the alert after the is dismissed I want to dispatch LoadService action from the same success effect

Comment: Do you understand me now?

Answer (score 0):

I presume from your comments and code you are trying to implement some UI behavior upon response from some service (LoginService). That code is fine for a library or for a service. But at some point you need to know the result, at some point you need to `subscribe()` to the observable you are creating in order to know it result

Make a `subscribe()` call at the end. Otherwise your observable will never materialize.

**UPDATE**

Besides the `subscribe()` call, you need to navigate to `/home` url and then in the component that handle that route load your business: `new businessActions.LoadBiz()`

your code should look to me like:

```
@Effect({ dispatch: false })
LogInSuccess$: Observable<any> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<businessActions.LogInSuccess>(
        businessActions.AuthActionTypes.LOGIN_SUCCESS
    ),
    map((action: businessActions.LogInSuccess) => {
        localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(action.payload));
    })
).subscribe(() => this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('/home'));
```

then where ever you handle `/home` route, in the init() method of the component `new businessActions.LoadBiz()` or better yet, extract `businessActions` logic into a service, inject the service and call: `businessActions.LoadBiz()` no need to call `new` in your UI then.

Comment: This is a simple illustration of what I am trying to do Login -> LoginSuccess -> [localstorage save then trigger LoadDetails before redirecting to another page]